# Rails 5.1 + Webpacker + React-router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, react-router, webpacker

I am trying to use all of these three in a new project.
I wanted to handle routing using `react-router`.

With the 'out of the box' setup it works fine when I start at e.g. `localhost:3000/` and then click for example `Link` routing to `signup` page. But when I try to enter `localhost:3000/signup` it says there is no route (as there is no such route created using Rails).

How am I able to integrate this?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `react-router-dom` with `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution to handle this situation is to define all your React routes within the Rails config/routes.rb files.

Thing is Rails has to know about the routes being handled by React, otherwise it'd try to take over and handle the routing for your application.

So, imagine your front controller route for your React is this: `root 'pages#index'` and looks like this in config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'pages#index'
end
```

So, to make your React routes work fine, without letting Rails interfere you can do this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'pages#index'
    get 'admin', to: 'pages#index'
    get 'admin/dashboard', to: 'pages#index'
    get 'admin/user', to: 'pages#index'
end
```

You just redirect all your React routes to the front controller 'pages#index'. That will do the job.